# Access in Enterprise Edition

Tags: enterprise, editions, developer-edition, record-access-level

I am bit new for Salesforce Editions,

I have one app, which fetch all Fields and show them on VF page from the objects Lead,Contact,Opportunity and Account.

Now, I have one "Enterprise Edition" org, where I have installed this app, here I am having "System Administrator" profile which do have access to all this object (all Read,write update access).

I am Unable to see here Account and Opportunity Objects in my picklist. and event unable to Update Lead and Contact records, which **work very fine in Developer Edition**

Comment: getting any errors ?

Comment: Do you mean it works in the Developer Edition your create the app in or in other developer Editions when you install it? If its the former, then you might have some namespace prefix logic that is being applied to the standard objects that do not have a namespace prefix.

Comment: Oh, Sorry for late replies, It was a silly mistake in my snipets ! @KeithC - Yes, It was something like that only, In Enterprise they are having other naming conventions (Changed label n all) where my universal working code was facing issue for them only.